# SSIS Truncating decimal points of number

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am running an SSIS package which includes a decimal in a column of a flat file. This decimal is being written to a decimal (16,6) field in sql server but the value is being truncated at the decimal point. I.E. 12.45 to 12. No truncation warnings/errors appear.

I found lots of resources on how to truncate items in the SSIS but nothing about troubleshooting things being unintentionally truncated.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about the data task? What is the data type of the column in that data task?

Comment: Start by using viewers to determine at which point in the dataflow the data is being truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had never heard of viewers before. Using the viewer it appeared the ssis was truncating the numbers form the text file/ I just fixed it.

Thanks